# WPF A list of non-homogeneous views

Tags: c#, wpf, .net-core, mvvm

I have a WPF application that I want to present a list of non-homogeneous VIEWS. I want to have a button that I can write a handler for that would display a view. Then since it is a view the user could interact with it (enter values in a `TextBox` for example) using an underlying view model (MVVM). So let me explain further. The flow that I am looking to achieve is that a user selects which view to display. The view is displayed in a list. Then the user interacts with this instance of the view. When the user clicks on the button again a possibly different view is displayed and the user can now interact with two views. This continues as long as the 'add' button is clicked adding to the views in the list. This is further complicated because first, each of these views first are different. The particular view that should be displayed is dependent on a parameter that is passed to the command. Second it is complicated because each of these views also have dependencies that are passed in via IoC and on down to the associated view model. In other words there is not a parameterless constructor for the view models. So I cannot define a view model/view relationship like:

```
<Window.Resources>
   <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type views:SelectCustomerViewModel}"\>
        <views:SelectCustomerView/>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

I have searched and I see that one solution that comes close using the `ItemTemplateSelector` as outlined [here](https://www.dotnetcurry.com/wpf/1211/wpf-items-control-advanced-topic). But as far as I can tell this only is a solution for a non-homogeneous display. If I revert to a list of views then it seems like I am breaking the MVVM model, as I would have to construct an appropriate view and assign the appropriate view model. How should I display/bring up a dynamic list of different views using the IoC from `App.Xaml.cs`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `ItemTemplateSelector` is a perfectly valid way of showing a different view (or portion of a view) for (possibly disparate) items that are shown in a list. Under the hood this is an implementation of a strategy pattern, where the view is chosen based on the data item.

However it seems that a tab view would also fit your criteria - as the command is triggered you instantiate a new tab for the required view. This view can be bound to the same viewmodel, so you could have changes from one tab being echoed on another tab. IIRC there are some tab view implementations that include something similar to a `ItemTemplateSelector` (because a tab view is a variation on  a list control).

As for the IoC - don't be concerned about complexities there. Most IoC implementations will allow you to specify constructor parameter values or expressions as part of registering types.

Comment: So if the view that is to be displayed has TextBox type input this is acceptable? From the examples I saw only readonly/displayonly "templates".

Comment: @KevinBurton sure, input controls are acceptable. With the examples you saw there might be one or two issues at play: 1) only simple examples are used for the purposes of the article; 2) or the list controls being used differentiate between read only and editable modes (i.e. grid rows are like this, they have a read only template and an editing template). You won't have this "mode" issue with something like a tab view.